# Undefined symbols using wsdl2objc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, soap, wsdl

I am trying to use wsdl2objc with  [this](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl) soap web service. But when am using it in my iPhone project , I am getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_ndfdXML", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@ndfdXML in HomeViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here i used ndfdXML class.

```
ndfdXMLBinding *binding = [ndfdXML ndfdXMLBinding];
binding.logXMLInOut = NO;
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

This is the error am getting now

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_typens_sectorTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_CornerPoints main] in ndfdXML.o
  "_typens_featureTypeTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_GmlLatLonList main] in ndfdXML.o
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_GmlTimeSeries main] in ndfdXML.o
  "_typens_compTypeTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_GmlTimeSeries main] in ndfdXML.o
  "_typens_productTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_NDFDgen main] in ndfdXML.o
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_NDFDgenLatLonList main] in ndfdXML.o
  "_typens_formatTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_NDFDgenByDay main] in ndfdXML.o
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_NDFDgenByDayLatLonList main] in ndfdXML.o
  "_typens_displayLevelTypeStringFromEnum", referenced from:
      -[ndfdXMLBinding_LatLonListCityNames main] in ndfdXML.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

didn't get an answer.. This wsdl2objc is not working for all wsdl...i switched to http://sudzc.com/   .It is also converts wsdl 2 ObjC

Comment: Ya...some times we have to modify codes little bit to make it work...Some problems may happen... wsdl2objc also have same problem.